# Ocelot error on sending multiple requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, ocelot, backoffice

I'am using ocelot to manage my backoffice. However, in my frontend when I send multiple request in one page like the following image:

[requests screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYA8P.png)

I got 502 bad gateway error.

My endpoints are correct I can send same request from postman.

I tried updating last version of ocelot. Currently I was using 16.0.1 and I updated to 23.0.0